# OpenGL fragment shader has no effect, how to determine the error?

Tags: c++, opengl, osx-lion

I'm running Mac OS X Lion and I'm trying to write a basic OpenGl program but my fragment shader isn't working. When I don't include it, I get my black triangle but when I do the screen is just white. I also get no errors loading it. What is the best way to debug this? Here are my shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 120
attribute vec2 coord2d;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 120
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor[0] = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor[1] = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor[2] = 0.0;
}
```

And the code to load my shaders I gained from [this tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_02).

Edited to add more information

```
int init_resources()
{
    GLfloat triangle_vertices[] = {
        0.0f,  0.8f,
        -0.8f, -0.8f,
        0.8f, -0.8f,
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_triangle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_triangle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_vertices), triangle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLint link_ok = GL_FALSE;
    GLuint vs, fs;
    if ((vs = create_shader("vertShader.sh", GL_VERTEX_SHADER))   == 0) return 0;
    if ((fs = create_shader("fragShader.sh", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)) == 0) return 0;

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_ok);
    if (!link_ok) {
        fprintf(stderr, "glLinkProgram:");
        print_log(program);
        return 0;
    }

    const char* attribute_name = "coord2d";
    attribute_coord2d = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute_name);
    if (attribute_coord2d == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind attribute %s\n", attribute_name);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void onDisplay()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(program);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord2d);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_triangle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                          attribute_coord2d, 
                          2,                 
                          GL_FLOAT,          
                          GL_FALSE,          
                          0,                 
                          0                  
                          );

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord2d);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

GLuint create_shader(const char* filename, GLenum type)
{
  const GLchar* source = file_read(filename);
  if (source == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s: ", filename); perror("");
    return 0;
  }
  GLuint res = glCreateShader(type);

  glShaderSource(res, 1, source, NULL);
  free((void*)source);

  glCompileShader(res);
  GLint compile_ok = GL_FALSE;
  glGetShaderiv(res, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
  if (compile_ok == GL_FALSE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:", filename);
    print_log(res);
    glDeleteShader(res);
    return 0;
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're on the right track checking error codes and checking shader compile status, though beyond without seeing code  it's difficult to prescribe something else to check. Getting to a point with OGL where you can actually do some debugging takes a bit of a leap, you have to get a lot of boilerplate right to get your first triangle to appear. If you want to put up what you've got I might be able to spot something, though I can appreciate if you want to debug it yourself.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I added a the only other functions I think are relavant. But is there no debugger of sorts for issues like this?

Comment: Usually you can find most bad things by calling glGetError. There's also gdebugger which is nice software, but it's more for inspecting contents of buffers and textures and such. It won't explicitly tell you why you don't have a triangle on the screen.

Comment: hm, glGetError returns 0 and gdebugger isn't compatible with lion. I'll keep looking for the bug, Cheers.

Comment: Your code looks perfect to me, I can't see any problems there. I could miss something, but it looks correct.

Comment: Ah, I needed to add gl_FragColor[3] = 1.0; (for opacity I believe) I feel dumb, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to add gl_FragColor[3] = 1.0; as I wasn't setting opacity.

Comment: By the way, instead of setting those individual components separately, just use `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);`. This is GLSL and not C. It would even have prevented your problem, since assigning a `vec3` to a `vec4` is an error and you would have to explicitly add a 4th component.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile you found your solution, it seems, but I wanted to give you another tip, which helped me (also quite new to all this) a lot recently, particularly if you are working on Mac OS X:

I suggest you install the "Graphics Tools for XCode" (available from the developer downloads section), which will help you a lot to develop your shaders, in particular:

- OpenGL Shader Builder which helps you develop and test shaders
- OpenGL Profiler which not only helps you to profile your application, but you can also see what resources are loaded etc and in your case: You can set a breakpoint to stop execution (for example before swapping) and then view the shader that is loaded, and modify it at runtime, to see what effect the change has

Here is the User Guide for OpenGL Profiler:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLProfilerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006475-CH1-DontLinkElementID_31

Hope that helps

Comment: Awesome, these were the kind of tools I was looking for.